# iOS 13.4.1 blocks ASP.Net session cookie in an iframe

Tags: ios, asp.net, iframe, session-cookies

I have an ASP.Net website that can be placed in an iframe.  I have implemented the fix where the top level frame redirects to our site to set a 1st level httponly secure session cookie.  Then we redirect back to the calling page and use Storage Access API to grant access to the session cookie in the iframe.  With the release of iOS 13.4.1, the redirect from our site back to the calling page no longer works.  It redirects back to the default page of the domain. I do the redirect using javascript/jquery.  I have tried doing server redirects, meta refresh redirects, and while they redirect to the correct page, there is no session cookie to grant access to.  Here is the js redirect (if there is a page to return to in the querystring - ?returl=somesite/somepage it will use that, otherwise it redirects back to document.referrer):

```
'''
// page is loaded
function SetupOnChangeEvents() {
  if (window.location.search != "") {
    var retVal = window.location.search.substr(8);
    window.location.replace(retVal);
  }
  window.location.replace(document.referrer);
}
'''
```

Comment: Webkit enforfces third party cookie blocking in iOS 13.4 (and Safari 13.1) - see https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/

I'm seeing a similar problem.  My journey is top window mydomain.com hands off to iframe calling a page in mydomain.com (which can read the session cookie).  mydomain.com (in iframe) calls vendordomain.com and the user completes a vendor journey.  Vendor hands back to mydomain.com and this callback page cannot read the session cookie.   I know I need to implemented Storage Access API, but if you're having issues?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to do the sandboxing on iframe as described here: https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/
I figured out why the redirect was going back to the domain (sort of).  document.referrer still just has the domain and not the page, and it continued execution, so I needed to do add a return; statement after the first window.location.replace.  I can see the session cookie getting set in my domain, but when it returns to the top level domain, it is disappeared before I even get to ask for Storage Access.  Access is granted, but there is nothing there.